# How can we set background color and tint color only for android using react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Am trying to change the background color of the tab bar only in android using "**react navigation**". Is it possible ?

I use the below tabBarOptions, but it changes the background color both in iOS and Android, but my requirement is to change the color only in Android and it should remain the default in iOS,

> {   tabBarOptions: {
>       style: {
>       backgroundColor: '#2D61A9',   }   } }

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Platform` [see here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html) to set platform os specific styles.

The following *should* work.

```
{
  tabBarOptions : {
    style: {
      Platform.select({
      android: {
        backgroundColor: '#2D61A9',
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple ios check using platform

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const style = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? {} : {backgroundColor: '#2D61A9'}

{ tabBarOptions: { style } }
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this syntax over the similar answer left three years ago? What benefits does it provide to implementors? Do you mind editing your answer with that information to help set it apart from the existing answer?

Comment: and does not work, it is not complete, Platform.select returns a complex object, you would still need to spread it  eg ...Platform.select()

The above code has no closing () and even if it has that, it will result to ```style: { {backgroundColor: '#2D61A9' }}```  instead of ```style: {backgroundColor: '#2D61A9'}```  @JeremyCaney